# Google Maps is grey after being called a second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps

I am looping through some JSON files and using the address from the JSON file for the google maps. I know the address is working properly because I set an alert to show the variable and it's showing what I expect. The call for the map is inside a click function. on one virtual page I have a list of customers and when the user clicks that customer, it redirects to another virtual page to display that customers information, with a map showing their address. When I do this for the first time , it works. If I click back, then select a different customer the map is just grey. Any idea why this is happening?

Here is my click function..

```
function cHandle(num) {
                    $("#custSpan" + i).on("click", function () {
                            window.location.href = "#CustInv";
                            custName = customer.Customer[num].compName;
                            $("#CustInvHead").html(custName);
                            $("#invoiceh2").html(custName + "'s Invoices");
                            $("#custInfo").empty();
                            $("#invoice").empty();
                            $("#map-canvas").empty();   
                            var inc = customer.Customer[num].compId;
                            $("#custInfo").append("Customer ID: " + customer.Customer[num].compId + "<br /><br />"
                                +"Customer Name: " + custName + "<br /><br />"
                                +"Customer Address: " + customer.Customer[num].compAddress + "<br /><br />"
                                +"Customer Contact: " + customer.Customer[num].compContact + "<br /><br />"
                                +"Customer Phone: <a href=\"tel:" + customer.Customer[num].compPhone + "\">" + customer.Customer[num].compPhone + "</a><br/ ><br />"
                                + "Customer Email: <a href=\"mailto:" + customer.Customer[num].compEmail + "\">" + customer.Customer[num].compEmail + "</a>"

                                );
                            address = customer.Customer[num].compAddress;
                            //alert(address);
                            codeAddress();
})
                }
                cHandle(i);
```

And here is my maps stuff..

```
function success(pos) {
            lat = pos.coords.latitude;
            lng = pos.coords.longitude;
            drawMap();
        }

        function error(err) {
            alert("Error " + err.code + " : " + err.message);
        }
        ;

        function codeAddress() {
            lat = 0;
            lng = 0;

            //Get the address
            //address = "123 Fake St";
            if (address == "") {
                alert("No Address Entered");
                return;
            }
                //Change address to coordinates to plot on map
            else {
                geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        var myLatLng = results[0].geometry.location;
                        lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                        lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                        drawMap();
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                        return;
                    }
                })
            }
        }
        function drawMap() {
            mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            var mapOptions = {
                center: mapCenter,
                zoom: 18,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

            };

            //Display the address
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

            //Map Marker
            var myLoc = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                position: mapCenter
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You call several times the creation of the map as you should call once (Initialize) map and call several times the function of creating the marker.

split the code in drawMap in two

first declare  the var map at top (window) level (outside the functions) 
and initialize your map
    
    var map

```
    function initialize() {
        mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        var mapOptions = {
            center: mapCenter,
            zoom: 18,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

        };

        //Display the address
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);


    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

second in the codeAddress() function call only the create marker function

```
 function createMarker() {

    var myLoc = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            position: mapCenter
        });
 }
```

Comment: I am not following how you want me to piece this together haha. I am attempting to do this, but it's not helping. Not sure if I am piecing it together how you are explaining it.